# Why would the icons in RailsAdmin just stop showing up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

I am not sure what I did, but the icons in the menu options don't show up anymore.

There are just squares, like below:

[image: Missing Icons in RailsAdmin]

What could have caused this and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: What icons? any code or a link to the project/site, can have a better look if there was some kind of example

Comment: There should be icons beside each of those links. There isn't a publicly available link right now. But in the screenshot, this is a standard RailsAdmin interface. There should be icons beside `Show, Edit, Delete, History, Show in app, Add a new listing category, etc.` Basically everywhere you see an empty square/box in the image I included in the question, there should be an icon there.

Comment: ok apologies if soft question but have you inspected in firefox/chrome to see if they are being rendered, is the path to the icon correct?

Comment: Yep...they are FontAwesome icons and that seems to be loading...and I am seeing no errors. The thing is, they used to work - but during the course of development, it just stopped working one day. It is possible that I may have done something, but I can't think of anything in particular - given that RailsAdmin is an engine that uses it's own stylesheet, icons, etc....none of which I tampered with intentionally...soo...not sure what's happening.

Comment: @Richlewis Here is an online version that shows the problem - http://realty-cloud.herokuapp.com/admin/  U: 'abc2@test.com', P: 'test2123'. Click on any of the models on the left, then you will see the broken icons on the right.

Comment: it has to be something with the url or the way they are being imported, only think i can think of is check the paths or are you using @import?  could you show how you are pulling them in, maybe comeone could spot something that you cant see?

Comment: I am not importing them manually. RailsAdmin is a popular Rails gem (engine) - https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin So it automatically handles the presentation. You can install it on any app you are using and see it - quite easily. I just can't figure out where my icons have disappeared to.

Comment: I had the same issue this morning as it happens, my path to call the icons was incorrect.. I still say you need to check the path, do you get this in the console when you render the page Served asset /rails_admin/fontawesome-webfont.woff - 404 Not Found (4ms)

Comment: Well normally app/assets/bootstrapandoverides.css.less for me but you say active admin serves its own CSS, so it could be in there but font awesome normally pulls in via where i stated

Comment: Yeh...well the issue is that I am not even seeing that 404 error, so it doesn't seem that is the issue.

Comment: Depends if your looking in the right place though

Comment: Have you got this on GitHub?

Comment: Nope....just on Heroku.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Have you managed to solve this Marc?

Answer (score 1):

This might be an ugly fix to the problem, but after trying everything is the only thing that worked for me.

Rails admin uses an old version of fontawesome. Download the zip file here: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/assets/font-awesome.zip

Then put the following files into the /public/assets directory of your rails project, from the /font directory in the zip file:

- fontawesome-webfont.eot
- fontawesome-webfont.svg
- fontawesome-webfont.ttf
- fontawesome-webfont.woff
- FontAwesome.otf

This is of course bypassing the proper rails asset pipeline, but as a workaround until rails admin is fixed will work fine.